# How to set Django to Ignore mysql errors and force mysql to insert a record?

Tags: mysql, django

So I am a naive Django developer and want a similar functionality as INSERT IGNORE of mysql in Django. Is there a way to do that? Right now whenever I try to save a record in my database, It throws (1364, Field doesn't have a default value). Should there be any change in Django settings or mysql settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute mySQL command in Django.

```
create_fields = ['f1', 'f2', 'f3']
values = [
    (1, 2, 3),
    (4, 5, 6),
    (5, 3, 8)
]
db_table = self.model._meta.db_table

values_sql = []
values_sql.append( "(%s)" % (','.join([ " %s " for i in range(len(create_fields))]),) ) # correct format

base_sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO %s (%s) VALUES " % (db_table, ",".join(create_fields))
sql = """%s %s""" % (base_sql, ", ".join(values_sql))
cursor.executemany(sql, values)
```